# Time hierarchy theorem for BPTIME

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

In [this](https://www.boazbarak.org/Papers/bptime.ps) paper, it is mentioned that BPTIME does not have a time hierarchy theorem, unlike DTIME. To quote the part where the author explains why:

> It must hold that for any $x$, either $\Pr[M(x) = 1] \geq \frac{2}{3}$
> or $\Pr[M(x) = 1] \leq \frac{1}{3}$. It is undecidable to test whether
> a machine $M$ satisfies this property and it is also unknown whether
> one can test if $M$ satisfies this property for a specific $x \in \{0,
> 1\}^{n}$ using less than $2^{n}$ steps.

Here are my questions:

1. Why is it undecidable to test for any $x$ whether for a probabilistic Turing machine $M$, whether $\Pr[M(x) = 1] \geq \frac{2}{3}$ or $\Pr[M(x) = 1] \leq \frac{1}{3}$? Can we not directly infer it from the string corresponding to the description of $\langle M \rangle$?
2. If (1) is "undecidable", why is the second fact (testing (1) for a specific $x \in \{0,
   1\}^{n}$ using less than $2^{n}$ steps) merely "unknown"? Why doesn't the same proof of undecidability work?
3. How are these two facts relevant to why BPTIME does not have a hierarchy theorem? In what specific step does the diagonalization argument break down when we are trying to prove a time hierarchy theorem for BPTIME?

Comment: The answer for (1) and (2) is quite simple - while you can check it for any single $x$ (by going over all possible values of the randomness, which takes exponential time), how would you test it for *all* $x$, of *all* lengths?

Comment: As for (3), I suggest trying to see how a diagonalization would work in this case.

Comment: (2) sounds clear. For a specific $x$, as you say, the best algorithm is exponential. It is unknown whether there is a better algorithm. But for (1), why is it "undecidable" and not merely "unknown"? Is there a formal proof of undecidability - perhaps a reduction to the halting problem?

Comment: Perhaps. Have you tried showing that the problem is undecidable?

Comment: I tried to reduce it to the halting problem, but did not go far. It seems very different from the setting of the halting problem.

Comment: Given a Turing machine $T$, let $M(x)$ simulate $T$ for $|x|$ steps. If $T$ halts, toss a fair coin. Otherwise, output $1$.

Comment: For (3), I'm following this lecture note (https://users.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/complectures/Arora/lec3.pdf) and trying to see where the contradiction lies. I am still not very sure. Is it the fact that when we are simulating a Turing machine with another, the overhead is now exponential because we have to consider all the random strings?

Comment: related https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/92779/lack-of-time-hierarchy-theorem-for-probabilistic-machines

Comment: Write the proof in full detail, and see what exactly is needed for it to go through. This is a useful skill to have.