# Does PromiseBPTIME have a time hierarchy theorem?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

This is a follow-up to [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/132830/time-hierarchy-theorem-for-bptime) question. Even though BPTIME does not have a time hierarchy theorem, the reasons that prevent it from having one are essentially bypassed by PromiseBPTIME. Thus, does PromiseBPTIME have a hierarchy theorem? If so, how does it look like and how to prove it?

Comment: Have you tried proving such a theorem? Try to emulate the proof of the time hierarchy theorem.